# ASP.NET MVC how to get name from another model by Id

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have got one question, how can I get category name in details.cshtml by foreign key - CategoryId in work model?

work.cs

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace InfoKiosk.Domain.Entities
{
    public class Work
    {
        public int WorkId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
        public Category Category { get; set; }
    }
}
```

category.cs

```
    public class Category
    {
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

The names of categories I choose from dropdownlist which one I populate from ViewBag.

details.cshtml

```
<dt>
    <strong>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Category):</strong> @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.???)
</dt>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this

```
<dt>
    <strong>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Category.Name):</strong> @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Category.Name)
</dt>
```

in your action include category

```
var model=context.Set<Work>().Iclude(c=>c.Category).FirstOrDefault(w=> w.WorkId==id);
return View(model);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass this in a `ViewBag` to the the view maybe from `Controller` :

```
string NameCategory = from c in context.Category
where c.CategoryId == work.categoryId
select c.Name
```